# Is it possible to make browsers ignore/disable all media queries?

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, fixed-width

Basically, I have to make a site fixed-width (temporarily) but unfortunately there are numerous CSS files with media queries all over the place, across all files. I've added a fixed pixel width to the `body` tag but the media queries are still having an effect when the browser is re-sized e.g. `div` elements clearing and shifting below other elements in the layout.

The only way I can think of is going through all the CSS files, commenting out all the media queries which could be a pain. Before I do this, do you know if there's a quicker way?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could split your media queries into a separate CSS file and use an if statement to decide whether or not to load them?

Comment: Thanks, that could be very useful in the future but I'd still have to sift through all the (Bootstrap and other) files gathering all the media queries... right now I need a quick way to make browsers just ignore all media queries site-wide so that the layout doesn't adapt.

Comment: No quick fix for this. Reconsider building fresh upon a more suitable framework - "media queries across all over the place" sounds like a nightmare. Or continue down the work-around path.. [Cough] find and replace...

Answer (score 1):

Body or wrapper, set a static width and use override.

body{
  width: 1280px !important;
}

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but, as mentioned before, many elements within the page are still affected by the media queries that target them.

Comment: You really need to jsFiddle this.  Without code, it's like needles in a hay stack.